# Basic fact in $L^p$ space

Tags: measure-theory

I'm studying $L^p$ space.

$1 \le p < r <q < \infty$ then $L^p \cap  L^q \subset L^r$.
More over $L^p \cap  L^\infty \subset L^r$

I'm trying to prove that fact. Which theorem is useful for proving that?

Comment: Which one is the basic fact and what fact are you trying to prove?

Comment: Sorry, my attached things make some confusion. so I'm trying to prove those basic facts Lp∩L1⊂Lr and Lp∩L∞⊂Lr.

Comment: What role does $q$ play?

Comment: Ah it's typo. I corrected $L^1$ to $L^q$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $f(x)\ge0$, Jensen's Inequality yields
$$
\left(\frac{1}{\int_X f^p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}\int_X f^{r-p}(x)f^p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\Large\frac{q-p}{r-p}}\le\frac{1}{\int_X f^p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}\int_X f^{q-p}(x)f^p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
which becomes
$$
\left(\int_Xf^r(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\Large\frac1r}\le\left(\int_Xf^p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\Large\frac1p\left(\frac{p}{r}\frac{q-r}{q-p}\right)}\left(\int_X f^q(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\Large\frac1q\left(\frac{q}{r}\frac{r-p}{q-p}\right)}
$$
Thus for $f\in L^p\cap L^q$,
$$
\|f\|_r\le\|f\|_p^{\Large\frac{p}{r}\frac{q-r}{q-p}}\;\|f\|_q^{\Large\frac{q}{r}\frac{r-p}{q-p}}\tag{1}
$$
where
$$
\frac{p}{r}\frac{q-r}{q-p}+\frac{q}{r}\frac{r-p}{q-p}=1\tag{2}
$$
Note that when $q\to\infty$, $(1)$ becomes
$$
\|f\|_r\le\|f\|_p^{\Large\frac{p}{r}}\;\|f\|_\infty^{\Large1-\frac{p}{r}}\tag{3}
$$

Answer (score 4):

**(1.)** For every positive real number $a$, one has $a^r\leqslant a^p+a^q$ (one can prove separately the cases $a\leqslant1$ and $a\gt1$). Thus, $|f(x)|^r\leqslant |f(x)|^p+|f(x)|^q$ for every $x$.

Hence $\|f\|_r^r\leqslant\|f\|_p^p+\|f\|_q^q$ and $\|f\|_r$ is finite for every $f$ in $L^p\cap L^q$. Thus, $L^p\cap L^q\subset L^r$.

**(2.)** For every positive real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a\leqslant b$, one has $a^r\leqslant a^pb^{r-p}$. Thus, $|f(x)|^r\leqslant |f(x)|^p\cdot\|f\|_\infty^{r-p}$ for every $x$.

Hence $\|f\|_r^r\leqslant\|f\|_p^p\cdot\|f\|_\infty^{r-p}$ and $\|f\|_r$ is finite for every $f$ in $L^p\cap L^\infty$. Thus, $L^p\cap L^\infty\subset L^r$.

**Note:** Although such uniform pointwise inequalities cannot yield optimal norm inequalities, they are (i) simple to prove, and (ii) sufficient to get the inclusions of spaces the OP is interested in.

Comment: Nice and simple (+1). If you polarize this inequality, noting that it holds equally well for $tf$, you get a homogenous inequality (with a constant between $1$ and $2$).

Comment: For any $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $tf$ also satisfies your inequality. Therefore,
$$
\|f\|_r^r\le t^{p-r}\|f\|_p^p+t^{q-r}\|f\|_q^q
$$
Minimizing the rhs yields
$$
t=\left(\frac{r-p}{q-r} \frac{\|f\|_p^p}{\|f\|_q^q}\right)^{\Large\frac{1}{q-p}}
$$
plugging the latter into the former yields
$$
\|f\|_r\le\left(\left(\frac{q-r}{r-p}\right)^{\Large\frac{r-p}{q-p}} + \left(\frac{r-p}{q-r}\right)^{\Large\frac{q-r}{q-p}}\right)^{\Large\frac1r} \|f\|_p^{\Large\frac{p}{r}\frac{q-r}{q-p}} \|f\|_q^{\Large\frac{q}{r}\frac{r-p}{q-p}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Some hints:**

$(1.)$ For $L^{p}\cap L^{q}\subset L^{r}$, take and $f\in L^{p}\cap L^{q}$ and divide the integration domain $X$ to $A:=\{x\in X:|f(x)|\leq 1\}$ and $A^{c}$. What can you say about $|f(x)|^{r}$ for $x\in A$ or $x\in A^{c}$? What can you conclude for $\|f\|_{r}$?

$(2.)$ Start showing that if $f\in L^{p}$ then $\mu(A^{c})<\infty$. Then use the fact that $|f(x)|\leq \|f\|_{\infty}$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and use the same logic as in the previous step to conclude $\|f\|_{r}<\infty$ if $f\in L^{p}\cap L^{\infty}$.

If you need some more hints or can't get started with these; we can discuss at the comment section below.