# Schwartz class estimation.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I have a function $f\in \mathcal{S}$ (i.e of Schwartz class), and I want to show there exist constants $C,k>0$ s.t 
$$\|f\|_p \leq C(\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)| + \sup_{\mathbb{x\in \mathbb{R}}} |x^k f(x)|)$$
for every $ p \in [1,\infty]$.

For $p=1,\infty$ it's obvious from definition, I mean I can take f with compact support and this will prove for $p=1$, for $p=\infty$ it's trivial.

But for $ p \in (1,\infty)$ I find myself at a mess, I need to do integration by parts inductively but I don't seem to find the right approach, I guess I need to use here Leibnitz general product rule, but I don't see how to come to suitable constants.

Any help , is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: 
$$
\|f\|_p^p=\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{|f(x)|^p(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|
$$
and
$$
\|f\|_1\le\pi\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|(1+x^2)
$$
since $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}=\pi$.

Now apply [inequality $(3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/157670/13854) with $p=1$.